# Can I work with eclipse-m2e and not having the container restart when a class is compiled?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am working with a Java/Maven/Spring application stack, using Eclipse and m2e integration.  Everything works well for the most part but it is slightly annoying that the default behaviour is to restart the whole application context in the servlet container when a class is recompiled.

In previous application stacks I've worked with I've been able to have app contexts remain running and classes hot deploy when running in debug mode (using Jetty, so long as the method signatures don't change).

Is this not something that is readily supported with m2e integration?

Comment: Have you tried the solution [mentioned on this post](http://www.clickonchris.com/2010/05/configuring-jetty-maven-and-eclipse-together-with-hot-deploy/) ? If that fails you can always use a product like Jrebel which will deploy the change without a restart.

Comment: We are on tomcat as our container so that's not an option for us.

Comment: @anger it doesn't matter which container to use. But give JRebel a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure [Jrebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) can handle the hot deploy for you. I had a similar problem while working with a web app whose dependencies were governed with maven. It was also deployed on tomcat and I got Jrebel to hot deploy the code.

I came across a [plugin called manik](https://code.google.com/p/manik-hot-deploy/) that claims to perform hot deployment for maven projects on eclipse, but I've not tried it myself. That can be an option if you can get it to work with your project.